# Datefield Extjs to show years less than 100

Tags: extjs, extjs5, extjs6, extjs6-classic, datefield

I have a date-field and I need to set the default date as 01-01-0001 but the date-field is not showing/picking the dates less than 100. if i select a date 01-01-0001 it shows 01-01-1901.And it i don't select and directly type 01-01-0001 it is saving in the database as 01-01-0001 but while displaying it is showing 12-30-0000

in the model I am using read and write format this way. `{
            type: 'date',
            name: 'shipDate',
            dateReadFormat: 'time',
            dateWriteFormat: 'c'
        },
Not sure what is wrong.`
[Fiddle example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2e6s)

Answer (score 0):

Your model definition can be:

```
Ext.define('testmodel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {
        name:'f_date', 
        type:'date', 
        dateFormat: 'c', 
        dateWriteFormat: 'd-m-Y',
        dateReadFormat: 'd-m-Y'
        }
    ]
});
```

And date input field definition can be:

```
{
    xtype: 'datefield',
    anchor: '100%',
    fieldLabel: 'To',
    name: 'to_date',
    format: 'd-m-Y'
}
```

I don't know what is your database, but with these settings I can successfully read and write from MS SQL Server.

Comment: can we set a default date to 01-01-0001 when the value is empty or null?

Comment: even mine is sql in the db i can see 01-01-0001 but while displaying is is showing me 12-30-0000